# Very simple socket code in php - putting data is ok, but returns nothing

Tags: php, sockets

I need to post some data to the listening serwer and get answear using sockets in php.

Putting work fine (receiver get what he needs), but when I try to get any serwer answear I just cant. It just goes over and over and over... looks like `while` never ends but why? (on the serwer side team check and say that responce is submitet to me).

I use Php but serwer is c++ (I heard this might be the problem)

The code:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 36000); // to test the shile for a longer time, but aparentry responce goes right away

$fp = fsockopen("192.168.x.x", 9999, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {

    echo "Connected<br />\n";

$out = chr(11)."MSH|....some fields there....|".chr(28).chr(13); //chr(x) are ruquired by serwer

if ( fputs($fp, $out, strlen($out)) )
{

    echo "<br />\nwriting message<br />\n";//if I eomment the while below this will show without problem

    while (!feof($fp)) {
       echo fgets($fp, 1024);
    }//just goes and goes... never finding end of file (I gues)
}

    fclose($fp);
}
```

I used 3 different ways in php to open socket and they all seem to have similar issue. How can I test what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try fwrite instead of fputs, but your code looks fine, you should describe what you use it for, which server and so on to get a bit documentation about it.

And choose TCP/UDP.

```
$fp = fsockopen('udp://192.168.X.X', '9999', $errno, $errstr, 10);
fwrite($fp, '\\xff\\xff\\xff\\xff\\');
```

And try this.

```
 do {
      $contents .= fgetc($fp);
      $socketstatus = socket_get_status($fp);    
    } while($socketstatus["unread_bytes"]); 

 echo $contents;
```